# How to serve relative files from HttpListener

Tags: c#, html, httplistener

I am learning the `HttpListener`.  I am creating a small app that is a webserver by using the `HttpListener` (following
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and https://www.codehosting.net/blog/BlogEngine/post/Simple-C-Web-Server.aspx).  Note, no ASP.NET stuff.

In my function that is called from `_responderMethod`, I basically return HTML (that is read from a physical file on disk) which contains something like:

```
   ...
   <link href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>
   ...
```

However, as to be expected, the `.css` and `.js` files don't seem to be served (I can tell because there's no styles or behaviors as expected on the client after the html has been served).

How do I go about serving this files, do I need to do something with `HttpServerUtility.MapPath`? if so, could you point me to some examples on that?

Or do I need to scan the HTML I am about to serve and open those files up (recursively) read and return those?  I hope not.

BTW, the C# code that serves this is as follows, where my `_responderMethod` just returns the string of the HTML file as it is stated above:

I initialize and start the server as follows:

```
WebServer ws = new WebServer(program.SendResponse, "http://<myip>:8080/");
ws.Run();
```

the class constructor is pretty much:

```
public class WebServer
{
    private readonly HttpListener _listener = new HttpListener();
    private readonly Func<HttpListenerRequest, string> _responderMethod;

    public WebServer(string[] prefixes, Func<HttpListenerRequest, string> method)
    { 
        // A responder method is required
        if (method == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("method");

        foreach (string s in prefixes)
            _listener.Prefixes.Add(s);

         _responderMethod = method;
         _listener.Start();
}
public WebServer(Func<HttpListenerRequest, string> method, params string[] prefixes)
    : this(prefixes, method) { }
```

the `.Run()` is:

```
public void Run()
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Webserver running...");
        try
        {
            while (_listener.IsListening)
            {
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((c) =>
                {
                    var ctx = c as HttpListenerContext;
                    try
                    {
                        string rstr = _responderMethod(ctx.Request);
                        byte[] buf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rstr);
                        ctx.Response.ContentLength64 = buf.Length;
                        ctx.Response.OutputStream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                    }
                    catch { } // suppress any exceptions
                    finally
                    {
                        // always close the stream
                        ctx.Response.OutputStream.Close();
                    }
                }, _listener.GetContext());
            }
        }
        catch { } // suppress any exceptions
    });
}
```

My `SendResponse()`:

```
public string SendResponse(HttpListenerRequest request)
{
      return File.ReadAllText(@"static\index.html");
}
```

Comment: I edited your question.  Unlike normal forum sites we do not need tags in the question title or salutations like `hi` or `Thanks` within the question.

Comment: Could you put the code in your question that shows the method for the listener? It would be the one with the HttpListener.Start method call.

Comment: The client is going to ask your server for those files. Are you seeing requests from the client (I assume it's a browser) for the .css and .js files? If so, are you serving them? What are you setting as the response content type when you serve the HTML?

Comment: Hey Adam, Jim, many thanks for helping out.  I've updated my post with more code now.  @JimMischel the client is a browser, let me check if I get requested for those files...I don't think I get those requests...

Comment: Actually, I am getting the requested files in request.m_RawUrl!  I don't know why I didn't check on that before posting. Now it is a matter of serving them.  What's the preferred way of doing that, in the same way with File.ReadAllText (if text) and File.ReadAllBytes (if binary like a PNG file)?

Comment: When debugging these things, it's useful to know exactly *what* is sent *where* (did the client request that css?). You can use [Fiddler](http://www.getfiddler.com) for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your HTML specifies script or CSS files that are on your site, the client browser is going to request them. Your server has to serve up those files, too. Scripts and CSS files are text files that you serve in much the same way that you serve HTML files, although you'll want to be sure to change the content type header accordingly. You serve binary files (images, etc.) in binary format. Again, you'll want to be sure to set the content type to indicate that it's an image.

Comment: Hi Jim,  thanks, I got it working.  As you mentioned, I needed to return the content type and return the data as byte[] from a File.ReadAllBytes, thanks!